# Problems reformatting a USB with React OS

Tags: 20.04

I am having issues reformating this USB that had ReactOS on it! I get this popup saying that it cant be reformatting because of the partition table! I tried everything to reformat it and nothing worked. I don't want to have to buy a new USB!

Comment: Was this on Ubuntu? (I ask because it's unusual to use Fedora Media Writer on Ubuntu.) If not, and it's not otherwise related to Ubuntu, then it's off-topic as detailed in the [help/on-topic] and should be closed, but could possibly be migrated to [unix.se].

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this issue via Fedora Media Writer (USB Restoration Option). When you open Fedora Media Writer just click the *Restore* button when your USB is plugged in.

Comment: I installed Fedora Media Writer and searched for the restore button but it was nowhere to be found. Please upload a screenshot of the restore button in Fedora Media Writer and link to it in a comment, so that I will be able to try it in my Fedora Media Writer.

Comment: Possible Issue Fixes

- Make sure your USB is plugged in
- Make sure there is a Live System in your USB partition Table

If none of this works alternatively you can reformat yourself in the file manager included in Ubuntu! 

How to Reformat a USB in Fedora Media Writer: There should be a Restore button when the USB is Plugged in and Fedora Media Writer is open! 

How to reformat the USB with File Manager built into Ubuntu: Plug in the USB then right click the USB on the left panel in File Manager! Then click Reformat and go through the reformat process! Feel free to ask more questions

Comment: https://www.fossmint.com/fedora-media-writer-tool-for-fedora-users/

Comment: Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f514f.png) of Fedora Media Writer installed in Ubuntu. On the Fedora screenshot the Restore button appears, but on my Ubuntu screenshot it does not appear. If you can please inform me how Ubuntu users can achieve this functionality without having to install Fedora in a virtual machine just to run than one app in it.

Comment: Please tell me what version of Ubuntu you are running so I can find another solution to your problem!

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 18.04. Fedora Media Writer is installed via flatpak, so like snap packages the same flatpak package would get installed in all Ubuntu versions that support flatpak. The real reason why I installed this app was to test it so that I could update [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/691798/) that I posted at Superuser back in 2013 when Fedora Media Writer was formerly named Fedora LiveUSB Creator.

Comment: You should use an alternative method of reformatting! Please consider using the Ubuntu File Manager to reformat your drive! Just right click the drive in File Manager and click reformat! Its works all the time and never fails!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109631/discussion-between-karel-and-jayden-w).